# Proving two sets are equal.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let A,B and C be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove (A$\cap$B)$^c$=C$\cup$A$^c$
>   given that
>
> 1) A$\subset$B$\cup$C
>
> 2) A$\cap$B and A$\cap$C are not empty.
>
> 3.) A$\cap$B$\cap$C=$\emptyset$

***What I have tried:***

1) x$\in$A implies that x$\in$B or x$\in$C.

2) and 3) imply that there exist some x$\in$A$\cap$B and some y$\in$A$\cap$C such that x$\neq$y.

Let's prove the equality of the sets by showing that (A$\cap$B)$^c$ $\subset$ C$\cup$A$^c$ and C$\cup$A$^c \subset$ $(A$$\cap$B)$^c$.

i) Let x$\in$(A$\cap$B)$^c$. Then x$\in$(A$\cap$B)$^c$  $\implies $x$\in$A$^c$$\cup$B$^c$ $\implies$ x$\notin$A$\cap$B $\implies$$\dots$

ii) Let x$\in$C$\cup$A$^c$. Then x$\in$C$\cup$A$^c$ $\implies$ x$\in$B$\cup$C$\cup$A$^c$

I know this problem is very elementary in the nature, but I am a little stuck - a nudge in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I wouldn't do it purely using equations, which is what you seem to be doing. I'd do it by cases. $x \in C \cup A^c $ means that either $x \in C$ or $x \notin A $. So start by assuming that $x \in C $, and prove that $x \in (A \cap B)^c $. Then assume instead that $x \notin A $, and prove the same thing. And use a similar approach for the other direction.